# Editing coordinates of GeoTIFF map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I have a GeoTIFF image imported in QGIS. Unfortunately when compared to older image I have of the same area, there is a slight shift in coordinated in the new image.

Assuming that I calculated the shift-difference between the two maps (X meters north, Y meters east), Is there any way to modify the original coordinates bundled with the GeoTIFF based on my calculation?

Comment: If image comes with .tfw file you can edit the origo with a text editor. Or you can use gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html and give the extent by using the -a_ullr parameter. Or you can georeference the image in QGIS with the georeferences.